# Solutions of linear differential equations

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

For which values of the parameter $\alpha$, every two solutions $y_1$,$y_2$ of the equation $y''+y'+8y = e^{\alpha x}$ satisfy: $$(\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} y_1(x) = 1) \land (\lim\limits_{\rightarrow \infty} y_2(x) = 0) $$

Any ideas about this one?

Thanks!

Comment: Recreational Mathematical Language your are using I must say.

Comment: I do not understand. Is $y_1,y_2$ are the basis solution for the homogeneous ode, or are they two different general solutions (including the particular solution) ? If they are general solutions, then you also have different constant of integrations there. So it depends also on these?

Answer (score 1):

$y_1-y_2$ is essentially the solution of corresponding homogeneous ODE viz. $y''+y'+\alpha y=0$. You can see that the auxiliary equation $m^2+m+\alpha=0$ being quadratic in nature guarantees  roots $m=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4\alpha}}{2}$ with negative real parts iff $(1-4\alpha)< 1$ or $\alpha> 0$.

Comment: @Gonçalo..Thanks for correction. But all in vain as OP has been changed.

Answer (score -1):

Its a linear damped  oscillator equation, for $\alpha$ being positive, with an external force $e^{\alpha x}$, reading $x$ as time and putting the force terms as negative accelerations on the right side, directed against the amplitude and the velocity.

By the condtion, that $u,v$ die out in time, it follows, that start conditions  $(y(0),y'(0))$ die out exponentially and  all four terms may have the same  limiting  exponential form. From the two possible coefficents
$$ e^{\alpha x} (\alpha^2 + 2 \alpha -1 )= 0  \implies  \alpha=-1\pm \sqrt 2$$
only the positive coefficient is damping. A negative $\alpha$ will explode the initial conditons.

By the general solution of an inhomogenuous linear equation, that is linear in the start values, one gets their coefficients

```
 Coefficient[
     DSolveValue[{y''[x] + y'[x] + \[Alpha]  y[x] == E^(\[Alpha] x),
                  y[0] == u, y'[0] == v}, y[x], x] //
     ExpandAll, #] & /@ {u,v} // FullSimplify // TrigToExp
```

$$\left\{\frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1-4 \alpha } x-\frac{x}{2}}+\frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1-4 \alpha } x-\frac{x}{2}}+\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1-4 \alpha } x-\frac{x}{2}}}{2 \sqrt{1-4 \alpha }}-\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1-4 \alpha } x-\frac{x}{2}}}{2 \sqrt{1-4 \alpha }},\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1-4 \alpha } x-\frac{x}{2}}}{\sqrt{1-4 \alpha }}-\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1-4 \alpha } x-\frac{x}{2}}}{\sqrt{1-4 \alpha }}\right\}$$

$\alpha$ has to have a positive real part, so that the square root of first exponentials yields a negative damping real part of the exponent$